# Assign standard color to each bar of dynamic bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I create the dataframe below and I assign to every `Var1` a specific color which I want to be standard every time I order my dataframe in a way that the `Var1` with the biggest value will be on top (in my shiny app). For some reason the colors that are displayed are completely different from those that I have assigned to my dataframe. It should be displayed like :

[image]

```
library(plotly)
Var1<-c("Hospitalized","Not hospitalized","Unknown")
Freq<-c(52475,66129,43955)
hos<-data.frame(Var1,Freq)

hos$Perc<-round((hos$Freq / sum(hos$Freq))*100, 1)
hos$Var1 <- factor(hos$Var1, levels = unique(hos$Var1)[order(hos$Freq, decreasing = F)])
hos$color<-NA
for(i in 1:3){
  if(hos$Var1=="Not hospitalized"){
    hos[i,4]<-"#60ab3d"
  }
  else if(hos$Var1=="Hospitalized"){
    hos[i,4]<-"#3e5b84"
  }
  else{
    hos[i,4]<-"#028c75"
  }
}
fig1 <- plot_ly(hos , x = ~Perc, y = ~Var1,
                type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
                name = c(as.character(hos[1,1]),as.character(hos[2,1]),as.character(hos[3,1])),
                colors = c(as.character(hos[1,4]),as.character(hos[2,4]),as.character(hos[3,4]))
) 

fig1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ifelse` (or `case_when`) to assign colors and not a `for` loop. In `for` loop you are comparing all the values together (`hos$Var1=="Not hospitalized"`) and not one value at a time. Try with this approach :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

hos %>%
  arrange(Perc) %>%
  mutate(Var1 = factor(Var1, Var1), 
         color = case_when(Var1=="Not hospitalized" ~ "#60ab3d", 
                           Var1=="Hospitalized" ~ "#3e5b84", 
                           TRUE ~ "#028c75")) -> hos


fig1 <- plot_ly(hos , x = ~Perc, y = ~Var1,
                type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
                name = ~Var1,
                marker = list(color = ~color)) 

fig1
```

[image]